# testthat in R: sourcing in tested files

Tags: r, testthat

I am using the `testthat` package in R and I am trying to test a function
defined in a file `example.R`. This file contains a call `source("../utilities/utilities.R")` where `utilities.R` is a file with functions written by me. However, when I am trying to test a function from `example.R`, sourcing it within the testing script gives the following error:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file '../utilities/utilities.R': No such file or directory
```

Could you please clarify how to run tests for functions in files that source another file?

Comment: Have you tried putting this file in the same folder?

Comment: Putting the file to the same directory and sourcing it as `source("utilities.R")` in `example.R` does not help: I get a similar error message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Might be a bit late, but I found a solution. Test_that sets the directory holding the test file as the current working directory. See the code below from test-files.r. This causes the working directory to be /tests. Therefore, your main scripts need to source ("../file.R"), which works for testing, but not for running your app.

https://github.com/hadley/testthat/blob/master/R/test-files.r

```
source_dir <- function(path, pattern = "\\.[rR]$", env = test_env(),
                       chdir = TRUE) {
  files <- normalizePath(sort(dir(path, pattern, full.names = TRUE)))
  if (chdir) {
    old <- setwd(path)
    on.exit(setwd(old))
  }
```

The solution I found was to add setwd("..") in my test files and simply source the file name without the path.  source("file.R") instead of source("../file.R"). Seems to work for me.

Comment: Since my tests, data, and functions are all in separate folders, I found that I needed to assign the working directory as such wd <- file.path(getwd(),'..') and then specify a functions_dir <- file.path(wd,'functions') and 
data_dir <- file.path(wd, 'data') inside a helper file. Each test file will then have access to those variables to source their functions and data.

Answer (score 10):

testthat allows you to define and source helper files (see `?source_test_helpers`):

> Helper scripts are R scripts accompanying test scripts but prefixed by `helper`. These scripts are run once before the tests are run.

So what worked perfectly for me is simply putting a file "helper-functions.R" containing the code that I want to source in "/tests/testthat/". You **don't** have to call `source_test_helpers()` yourself, testthat will automatically do that when you run tests (e.g., via `devtools::test()` or `testthat::test_dir()`).

Answer (score 0):

No great solution to this problem I've found, so far mine has been to set the working directory within each test using the package `here`.

```
test_that('working directory is set',{
  setwd(here())
  # test code here
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I put the `source("C:/Users/.../Utilities.R")` in the test file.